# How to confirm email sent from Google scripts MailApp.sendEmail?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with a list of email addresses and personalized content to send each day. I setup a google apps script to grab the data and send the emails and I'll use a time based trigger to run it daily.

What I still need is to return into the spreadsheet for each row that the mail successfully sent (have the **responseCell** value set with the currentdate) and I can't seem to find how to do that.

Here's what I have but I can't find how to setup a success handler for the mail send process to wrap that setValue in. Closest I found is to use the GmailApp function to search the sent folder but I'm sure there's a more elegant way to solve this.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("List of kids");
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:Fmaxrow
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getMaxRows() -1, 6);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var todayis = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[2]; // First column
    var message = row[4]; // Third column
    var subject = row[0] + "\'s health declaration for " + todayis;
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    var responseCell = sheet.getRange(2+Number(i), 6);
    responseCell.setValue(todayis);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't be so sure

Comment: If your code ran without error, you can assume that the email was sent correctly (provided that `data.length` i not `0` and the email address is correct).

Comment: What make you feel sure about that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is not doable at the present. May be in future updates it might be possible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).